Young adult murder mystery book series about a cop's daughter who works in the morgue after school
It's about this high school girl. She's a cop's daughter and she works in the morgue after school. Everything is fine until dead bodies start coming into the morgue looking fine on the outside but burned or cooked on the inside. The bad guy ends up being another kid in her school.

Hm. Not sure if this qualifies as science fiction or fantasy. Sounds like it could be, but not necessarily.

https://www.goodreads.com/series/40763-body-of-evidence?

https://www.fantasticfiction.com/g/christopher-golden/body-of-evidence/
